# TCP/IP Client / Server commands data

Tags: parsing, tcp, command, arrays

I have a Client/Server architecture (C# .Net 4.0) that send's command packets of data as byte arrays. There is a variable number of parameters in any command, and each paramater is of variable length. Because of this I use delimiters for the end of a parameter and the command as a whole. The operand is always 2 bytes and both types of delimiter are 1 byte. The last parameter_delmiter is redundant as command_delmiter provides the same functionality.

The command structure is as follow:

```
FIELD                  SIZE(BYTES)
operand                2
parameter1             x
parameter_delmiter     1
parameter2             x
parameter_delmiter     1
parameterN             x
.............
.............
command_delmiter       1
```

Parameters are sourced from many different types, ie, ints, strings etc all encoded into byte arrays.

The problem I have is that sometimes parameters when encoded into byte arrays contain bytes that are the same value as a delimiter. For example command_delmiter=255.. and a paramater may have that byte inside of it.

**There is 3 ways I can think of fixing this:**

1) Encode the parameters differently so that they can never be the same value as a delimiter (255 and 254) Modulus?. This will mean that paramaters will become larger, ie Int16 will be more than 2 bytes etc.

2) Do not use delimiters at all, use count and length values at the start of the command structure.

3) Use something else.

To my knowledge, the way TCP/IP buffers work is that ***SOME SORT*** of delimiter has to be used to seperate 'commands' or 'bundles of data' as a buffer may contain multiple commands, or a command may span multiple buffers.. So this

BinaryReader / Writer seems like an obvious candidate, the only issue is that the byte array may contain multiple commands ( with parameters inside). So the byte array would still have to be chopped up in order to feel into the BinaryReader.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to have the length of the message in the (fixed) first few bytes of a message. So you could have the first 4 bytes to denote the length of a message, read those many bytes for the content of the message. The next 4 bytes would be the length of the next message. A length of 0 could indicate end of messages. Or you could use a header with a message count.

Also, remember TCP is a byte stream, so don't expect a complete message to be available every time you read data from a socket. You could receive an arbitrary number of bytes at ever read.

Comment: Yeah I already keep a seperate 'accumulation' buffer that I append all incoming data too. I check this secondary buffer for any valid and complete data 'chunks' and process them recusivly. So you recommend using length instead of delimiters. Thank you for validating what I thought was the correct path to take.